# Convert Calendar instance to DateTime() in java

Tags: java, datetime, calendar

How can I convert a calendar instance to a Datetime instance in java without any new libraries. I have searched all over the net for this and am stuck.

The code below requires Datetime() instance to get the arabic month, the variable I would like to use/convert is a calendar instance.

```
DateTime_now = new DateTime(); 
DateTime_now.withChronology(IslamicChronology.getInstance(tzSAUDI_ARABIA, IslamicChronology.LEAP_YEAR_15_BASED)).getMonthOfYear()
```

Comment: What do you mean by `DateTime`? If you mean the Joda class, then Joda is a library by itself.

Comment: I mean this DateTime_now = new DateTime();

Comment: looks like this when printed 2018-06-14T23:22:08.739+10:00

Comment: where is the calendar instance you are trying to convert?

Comment: Calendar future_isha_cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                        future_isha_cal.setTime(future_isha);
                        future_isha_cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, isha_athan_inc);

Comment: future_isha is fetched from Datetime? Please be more clear and update your question accordingly

Comment: What library is DateTime_now? Please explain. And You have issue in code DateTime_now is not any kind of library, probably c/p issue. This is by my guess Yodatime lib.

Comment: my question is clear, not sure how to formulate. how can i format a calendar instance to a Datetime format?

Comment: What is the package imported to use `DateTime` ?

Comment: @Ossama what is `DateTime`? Is it `org.joda.time.DateTime`? Since there is no `DateTime` in default JDK, we have no clue about what `DateTime` you are talking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [DateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) documentation, you can find that the constructor [DateTime(Object)](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime%28java.lang.Object%29) can do it for you.

```
public DateTime(Object instant)
```

> Constructs an instance from an Object that represents a datetime.
>
> If the object implies a chronology (such as GregorianCalendar does), then that chronology will be used. Otherwise, ISO default is used. Thus if a GregorianCalendar is passed in, the chronology used will be GJ, but if a Date is passed in the chronology will be ISO.

So you can simply

```
DateTime now = new DateTime(Calendar.getInstance());
```

Or with a `Chronology` since you are using one, [`DateTime(Object, Chronology)`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime%28java.lang.Object,%20org.joda.time.Chronology%29)

```
public DateTime(Object instant,Chronology chronology)
```

> If the chronology is null, ISO in the default time zone is used. Any chronology implied by the object (such as GregorianCalendar does) is ignored.

*Note: as for the moment, the API is guest based on the Class and methods accessible.*